# Почему тема не устанавливается в vim?

Tags: vim

Установил тему, вот путь C:\Users\IonE.vim\colors\deus.vim

Вот тема https://github.com/ajmwagar/vim-deus/tree/1be965e7bc1c01e7db5e46dcd0e50d32d4eef434

Когда пишу :colorscheme deus, получаю ошибку

> E185: Cannot find color scheme 'deus'

использую windows
Почему не работает?

Comment: А в пути к файлу перед .vim слеш не потерялся?

Comment: @KoVadim, оказываеться нужно переместить тему в C:\Users\\*\vimfiles\colors\